# Terminate while(cin>>ch) from the terminal and continue program execution

Tags: c++, while-loop, terminal

I have the following exercise and the question asks to use Ctrl+Z to terminate the input of characters. I'm using Linux, I assume Ctrl+Z is for Cmd, I couldn't replicate it in the terminal. Is there a way to stop the first loop from the terminal and continue the program execution to get the results?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  queue<char> Q; char ch;
  while (cin >> ch){
    if (ch=='*')
        if (!Q.empty()) Q.pop(); else Q.push(ch);
  }
  while (!Q.empty()){ 
    cout << Q.front();
    Q.pop();
  }
return 0;
}
```

Input example: A B C * D E F * * G
Output: DEFG

The exercise is just an example, Is there a way to exit while(cin>>ch) from the terminal and continue with the rest of the program?

Comment: You want Control-D on Linux (Control-Z for EOF is a Windows abomination).

Comment: I tried Ctrl+D but I get no output, it's like terminating with Ctrl+C. Should I expect the program to continue if ctrl+D is used?

Comment: On Linux (and *nix in general), Control-C kills the program, Control-Z suspends the program, Control-D signals EOF (end of file).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it with different code to see if I can get any results

Comment: Your `while (cin >> ch)` loop is a perfectly good way of handling input and EOF, so the problem may be elsewhere. (It's possible you're getting confused by line buffering if you're expecting to see output immediately.)

Comment: Try to hit enter before Ctrl-D

Comment: ctrl+d works fine with other code but not here, so it probably has to do with using a queue, I will look into it further, let me know if you know why we have this behavior here